# FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex

I have an QueryException error, can someone help me, please
I want to attach pdf file which is converted before finish method, but when it comes to last part it seems something went wrong. I do not get, I searched a lot but could not handle it.

```
public void finish (Database.BatchableContext bc){
    // execute any post-processing operations        
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List <Tenant__c> tList= [SELECT Total_rent_fee__c, Bank_balance__c,Email__c, Card_number__c, Expiry_Date__c,CVV__c, Id, Name FROM Tenant__c ];
    
    for(Tenant__c t: tList){            
        List<String> addToSend = new List<String>{t.Email__c};
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        String cardNumber = t.Card_number__c; 
        String lastFourDigits = cardNumber.substring(cardNumber.length() - 4);
        Date deductedDate=date.today();
        mail.setToAddresses(addToSend);
        mail.setSubject('Rent Fee Deduction');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear '+t.Name+'!\n\nWe hope this email finds you well. This is to notify you that a rent fee deduction '+ 
                              ' of '+t.Total_rent_fee__c+ ' has been processed from your card ending in ******'+lastFourDigits+' on '+deductedDate+'Please note'+ 
                              ' that this deduction has been made in accordance with the rental agreement '+
                              ' you signed and the payment details provided by you. The fee has been deducted automatically '+
                              ' from your card to ensure timely and hassle-free payments.\n\nIf you have any questions or concerns regarding this deduction,'+
                              ' please feel free to contact us. We would be happy to assist you.\n\nThank you for your cooperation.\n\nBest regards,\n\nProperty Management Company');
        
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        String fileName='DeductionInfo'+'.pdf';
        attach.setFileName(fileName);
        
        ContentVersion conVersion =[SELECT Id, Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion 
                                    WHERE Title =:fileName LIMIT 1];
        attach.setBody(conVersion.VersionData);
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attach});
        mail.setToAddresses(addToSend);
        emails.add(mail);  
        
            if(!emails.isEmpty()){
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }
    }
    
}
```

}